# Two git repositories in one working directory

Tags: eclipse, git, working-directory

I have two git repositories in Eclipse.
Both repositories have multipe projects. I want to have all projects of both repositories in ONE working directory.
So the result should be somthing like that:

`C:\workspace\Project1_Repo_A
C:\workspace\Project2_Repo_A
C:\workspace\Project1_Repo_B 
C:\workspace\Project2_Repo_B
C:\workspace\Project1_git\.git
C:\workspace\Project2_git\.git`

How is that possible?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Answer (score 0):

Having two projects share the exact same work tree is probably a bad idea.
If you run `git add <file> && git commit` how would git know which of the two repos you are trying to commit to?

If you want all projects in the same folder, I would suggest you put the repos in different folders as follows:

```
C:\repos\Repo_A\Project1
C:\repos\Repo_A\Project2
C:\repos\Repo_B\Project3 
C:\repos\Repo_B\Project4
C:\repos\Repo_A\.git
C:\repos\Repo_B\.git
```

Then, if you have a limited amount of projects you want to be available in the same workspace directory, then just create symlinks to those projects inside the `workspace` dir.
E.g.:

```
mklink /D "C:\workspace\Project1" "C:\repos\Repo_A\Project1"
```